# How can I do multiplayer using Minecraft on iPad?

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I play Minecraft P.E. on my iPad Air, and I have a friend who does as well. My other friends say if you are near each other while playing, it will work. For me it clearly doesn't. I was wondering if you could help with this problem. So, is multiplayer possible on the iPad Minecraft P.E.

Comment: Are you connected to WiFi?

Answer (score 5):

**Local Area Network**

When on the same network, you and your friend can easily join each other's worlds. First, the host must load up a world. Then your friend taps on Play, and there should be an extra world with your username, highlighted in purple.

**Multiplayer for Minecraft PE**

You may buy an [app](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/multiplayer-for-minecraft-pe/id609704981?mt=8) for $2.99 that allows you to host and join servers with only your device. With the app, you can join PocketMine servers and servers created by other users. Voice chat is one of the features in this app that makes it great. However, there is a player limit of 4 on regular servers. Using this app to join PocketMine servers is better because it lists some great servers available to you.

**PockeMine-MP**

You can also host a server on a computer and then join on your device. Tap edit and then external. Enter your *public* IP and keep the port default if you do not know what to do. Make sure you know how to port forward, or this will not work. Remember that you have to manually add servers. You can find great servers on the [Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/237-mcpe-servers/).

Hope these solutions helped!

Answer (score 2):

If you go into Options, there should be a button marked 'Local Server Multiplayer'. The host must have this option on in order for you to join.

Answer (score 0):

First your friend has to join their world.
Second press play and once you do you will see a world with a highlighted in purple.
Finally press it and will be in your friends world.

Comment: Also you could buy a multiplayer app, but your friend have to have it too. First go to the app and press multiplayer.Second Once it is done loading get off the app. Finally Press minecraft and you'll see a wold that has a purple name and press it.